# Create a new Pandas Column with just the year of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df where 'per_end_date' is a Datetime object.

```
zacks_mktv_df[:4]

ticker | per_end_date | mkt_val
--------------------------------
A      | 2016-12-31   | 14648.84
A      | 2015-12-31   | 13704.02
A      | 2014-12-31   | 13751.83
```

I want to grab the year from every row in 'per_end_date' column and make another row out of it so for my table above it would look like.

```
ticker | per_end_date | mkt_val  |
--------------------------------------------
A      | 2016-12-31   | 14648.84 | 2016
A      | 2015-12-31   | 13704.02 | 2015
A      | 2014-12-31   | 13751.83 | 2014
```

I tried this.

```
zacks_mktv_df['per_fisc_year'] = zacks_mktv_df[zacks_mktv_df.per_end_date.dt.year]
```

Getting the folowing error:

```
IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
```

Comment: Try this: `zacks_mktv_df['per_fisc_year'] = zacks_mktv_df.per_end_date.dt.year`

Comment: Thanks @MaxU  that worked as well

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
zacks_mktv_df['per_fisc_year'] = zacks_mktv_df['per_end_date'].dt.year
```

If the column `per_end_date` is eg. `datetime64`.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve this with .assign as well as follows.

```
zacks_mktv_df.assign(per_fisc_year= zacks_mktv_df.per_end_date.dt.year)
```